How do I get a shader to detect when the bitangent requires flipping due to mirrored UVs?
I'm calculating the TBN matrix of a mesh with this node group:

It's been working well so far. However, it's now failing me because I have a model that has mirrored UVs on one side. When this happens, the bitangent is reversed, meaning shader effects are no longer correct on half the mesh.
Here's an example. For these images, I've plugged the N, T, and B directly into the shader output. Because the mesh is mirrored along the X axis, the X of each TBN component should always be inverted, while the Y and Z should always be untouched (and thus visibly mirrored).



In this example, the bitangent on the left side of the image needs to be reversed.

How do I detect this situation so I can fix it? I've been trying to logic through various vector operations, but most of the solutions I find across the internet are some form of:

"Unmirror the UVs." Not an option.
"Use the tangent.w." Which Blender doesn't have, to my knowledge.
"Cross product the T and B to get an N, then dot compare that with the real N." I don't understand how this one helps because this just gives back the same original N. Trying it anyway didn't help. (I suspect the "faceforward" vector operation is for this, but again, from where am I getting the "true" vector?)

Also, while I'm currently only dealing with UVs mirrored along U, I may find in the future that I need any solution to also work with UVs mirrored along V. I don't think this will matter because both are just "is the vertex order clockwise or counterclockwise", but just to put it out there.
EDIT: I've created an example .blend that may be a bit easier to understand than the above images.


Any special reason you're recalculating the tangent? It's your input and yet you recalculate it from B x N.

Are these objects really "mirrored"? Or are they "negatively scaled"? I see negative scales can disrupt the right hand rule, but mirrors, not really.

Can you reproduce this with cubes? I can't understand your object and I believe I should definitely see some blue in the normals.


If the object has a normal map (the example doesn't), I need the TBN to be affected by that.
Well, if I select the verts and scale X by -1 (and flip normals), they look correct. They're extracted from a game so it's all "raw", no modifiers.
Okay I maybe didn't take the best pictures, I had the vectors converted into camera space (something needed for this specific model but not the general case). My understanding is that this shouldn't matter.


I've added an example .blend to the question. It's not 100% the same as the pictured example but maybe it'll be easier to understand.

I find the file you shared following the right had rule correctly for all cases... you mean you need to use a "left hand rule" when the UV is mirrored? Wouldn't "that" make the shaders wrong?

Hadn't thought of it that way, but I guess that's correct. I need calculating the B of the TBN to be left-handed when the UV is mirrored.

The following blenderartists.org answer got me what I needed: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-have-a-shader-detect-mirrored-uvs/1557016/2
Basically, using the Normal Map node allows for getting any TBN vector without having to cross other TBN vectors. Just like how [0.5,0.5,1.0] gets you the N, [1.0,0.5,0.5] gets you T, and [0.5,1.0,0.5] B. One of these vectors can then be dotted with the "raw" vector from a Normal or Tangent input - if the result is negative, it's pointed the other way, and thus the UV is mirrored.
